# Azure Storage - Firewall and Endpoints usage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-network

I have recently come across the Private Endpoint feature in Azure Storage and trying to implement it for secure access from a VNet. However, I am getting access issues while using Firewall, Virtual Network Service Endpoint and Private Endpoint all together.

I have two VNets (VNet1 & VNet2) in my subscription and an on-premises machine with Public IP to connect to Azure Storage. Following is my setup.

1. **VNet1** with a Subnet enabled with Service Endpoint feature is whitelisted in Storage account firewall.
2. Next, I have created a Private Endpoint to this storage account (for blob service) from **VNet2** which is also hosted inside the same Vnet.
3. Finally, I have whitelisted the **Public IP** of my on-premises VM to connect to the storage account under Firewall section.

Given the above setup, when I am trying to access this storage account blob containers inside a VM placed under VNet2, I am getting authorization issues.

May I please check if this setup is valid? Do Private Endpoint and Service Endpoint features work in Parallel?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [private endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-private-endpoints#conceptual-overview) can be created in subnets that use *[Service Endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-service-endpoints-overview)*. Clients in a subnet can thus connect to one storage account using private endpoint, while using service endpoints to access others.

There are multiple ways to connect to storage account:

1. Using a private endpoint (*private* link) to connect to storage account: Please find the referred document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/tutorial-private-endpoint-storage-portal).
2. Using Service Endpoint and Private endpoint: Please find the referred document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/vnet-endpoint-storage-event-hub?tabs=storage-account).

You can find more details in [this public document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/virtual-network-service-endpoints-and-firewalls-for-azure-storage-now-generally-available/).